# If JSONP easily works around cross domain constraints, why do browsers even bother anymore?

Tags: javascript, browser, same-origin-policy

If JSONP easily works around cross domain constraints (same origin policies), why do browsers even bother anymore?
I'm racking my brain for a reason, but all I come up with is that it's actually worse and provides an illusion of safety.

Comment: Well, it works around same origin policy restrictions as far as GET goes, but as you can't POST with JSONP, there's a difference in the scope of what is insecure about it. It does share the same insecurities as cross domain access as far as retrieving a payload from a server.

Comment: Why do *browsers* bother? Why do lifeless pieces of compiled code *bother*? Say what you really mean, not this. Browsers don't *choose* anything, they execute. And unless there's a good reason, developers of browsers generally don't remove functionality. And it's pretty hard to remove something as fundamental as the ability to load a script from another domain, which is essentially what JSONP is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple, it bases on ***TRUST***. If there is no trust, you ***cannot*** do JSONP. For example: if domain `abc.com` does not trust `def.com`, `abc.com` just does not support JSONP and `def.com` cannot utilize JSONP (or CORS).

Both server and client have to trust each other for JSONP to work (including CORS)

- The server trusts the client and supports JSONP (CORS)
- The client trusts the server that the script returned from the server ***does not compromise javascript on the page***. Because in order to use JSONP, the client loads the script and execute it using script tag => very dangerous.

When you implement your code, usually ***both domains are under your control*** and there is no harm doing that. In other cases, for example `yourdomain.com` and `evil.com` do not trust each other => browsers block cross-domain requests to ensure security.

> JSONP easily works around cross domain constraints

No, you ***cannot always*** use JSONP. JSONP only works if there is trust between browser and server.

Answer (score -1):

JSONP does *not* work around cross domain constraints. Not at all.

Forget the term JSONP. It's just a `<script>` element, typically but not necessarily inserted into the DOM dynamically. Nothing more, nothing less.

It's always been possible to load `<script>` elements from any domain. There's no cross domain restriction on `<script>` elements.

And that's all JSONP is. It's just a convention for using a `<script>` element. It's not related in the slightest to any of the other cross-domain constraints, because it doesn't use the mechanism that is subject to those constraints.

Note that you can't just decide to use JSONP to access a JSON resource across domains. If the resource is pure JSON you won't be able to read it unless it's in the same domain or allows access via CORS. There's nothing you can do from the browser to change this. The server has to provide the resource as an executable script, i.e. JSONP.